# Flutter is good for the future or kotlin is the best and what the best for mobile development?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

Flutter is good for the future or react native  is the best and what the best for mobile and whatis good for mobile development to future and what is good career crossplat form or android developer

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I flagged your question for closure and removal as it not fulfilling the SO guidelines. `what is best...` will elad to an opinion-based anwser and as such are not allowed here. A Question must contain a specific coding issue. Your question is conceptional and seeking for recomendation and as such iss off-topic here.

Comment:  Check out this insightful blog post on the most crucial digital tech skills for the next 5 to 10 years!  It covers AI, data science, cybersecurity, cloud computing, IoT, UX design, and blockchain. Don't miss out on future-proofing your career!  Read the full article here: bit.ly/3pAIXub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin is for Native Android App Development (only Android) and Multi-Platform (Android and iOS) but Multi-Platform still is not suitable to work around.

Flutter is stable and used by many. It is used to develop a cross-platform app (Android and iOS).

If your budget is low and your requirement is less then go for flutter and if you have a budget and a high demand requirement then Kotlin for native development is a good option.

Those are different. It is your choice.

Comment:  Check out this insightful blog post on the most crucial digital tech skills for the next 5 to 10 years!  It covers AI, data science, cybersecurity, cloud computing, IoT, UX design, and blockchain. Don't miss out on future-proofing your career!  Read the full article here: bit.ly/3pAIXub

Answer (score 0):

I have created Apps with Flutter and React and in my opinion you can do many things with each of them. I really enjoyed the dev experienct with react native with expo on the top.
There are plenty of Components which you can import and you do not have to program by yourself.
Another advantage of react native is, that if you already have some experience with react, you will have absolulty no trouble to pick it up. I guess its nice the other way round as well. So if you learn react native you will probably be able to build some Websites in React as well in the Future.

So maybe if I would recommend a Cross Platform Technology I would pick React-Native with Expo.
Javascript is a very popular language as well and you can use in many other Projects.
With Flutter you use Dart, and I ve seen Dart only in Flutter, so Javascript is probably more efficent to learn.

Maybe this helped you a bit ;D